# Set folder and file permissions without SSH

Tags: ssh, ftp, cron, file-permissions

My hosting provider refuses to give access to my shared hosting plan via SSH.
The problem is that i want to set the permissions for ALL folders to 755 and ALL files to 644 but i have no idea how to apply the changes to all files&folders via FTP connection.

My guess is to use cron job, but could not find out how to do that.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using shell_exec via php?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Check first if shell_exec function is enabled in your web hosting. 
An alternative can be looking for an option in your ftp client.

Comment: Not enabled :( Any other suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure but try using Filezilla, right click on file/folder -->file attributes